# Spring boot Autowiring service implementation in a bean fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to autowire a service implementation in one of my beans, but I keep getting a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. This is my code:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface GlobalPropertiesRepository extends BaseRepository<GlobalProperties, Long>{
}
```

Service:

```
public interface GlobalPropertiesService {
    GlobalProperties findOne(Long id);
}
```

Base Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    void delete(T deleted);
    List<T> findAll();
    List<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);
    T findOne(ID id);
    T save(T persisted);
    <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity);
}
```

Service Impl:

```
@Service("globalPropertiesService")
public class GlobalPropertiesServiceImpl implements GlobalPropertiesService{

    @Autowired
    GlobalPropertiesRepository globalPropertiesRepository;

    @Override
    public GlobalProperties findOne(Long id) {
        return globalPropertiesRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

And then I autowire the implementation in one of my beans as below:

```
public class GlobalPropertiesLoader {

    @Autowired
    private GlobalPropertiesService globalPropertiesService;

    private GlobalProperties globalProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        globalProperties = globalPropertiesService.findOne(1L);
    }

    public GlobalProperties getGlobalProperties(){
        return globalProperties;
    }           
}
```

Finally, this is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppServiceConfig {

    public AppServiceConfig() {
    }

    // Global properties
    @Bean(name="globalPropertiesLoader")
    public GlobalPropertiesLoader globalPropertiesLoader(){
        return new GlobalPropertiesLoader();
    }

}
```

This is my SpringBoot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")
public class TrackingService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackingService.class);

    static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TrackingService.class, args);

        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
            String basePackage = "...";
            Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);
            for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
                LOGGER.info("Component: "+component.getBeanClassName());       
            }

            context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            context.refresh();
            context.close();

    }

}
```

Now, when I try to start the application, I get the following error in my GlobalPropertiesLoader bean:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [GlobalPropertiesService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Does your Main Class have the `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question with the starter file.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is unnecessary as it is already being mentioned by `@SpringBootApplication`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java

Comment: Yes, I had added it just to make sure that all my components are getting picked. But it didn't help me anyway.

Comment: Which packages are you scanning and what packages are all the relevant classes in?

Comment: I'm scanning the base package. All the relevant classes are in the sub-packages. But I don't think I need the `@ComponentScan` . `@SpringBoot` does that automatically.

Comment: Where does the `BaseRepository` come from? I copied your source and tried it with a `CrudRepository` (does also have the `findOne()` method) and used `spring-data-mongodb` as my datastore. Works for my.

Comment: @alexvetter `BaseRepository`is my custom repository. Did you try my code as is (apart from changing to `CrudRepository`)? I changed it to `CrudRepository` but I still get the error.

Comment: @drunkenfist Yes, exactly the same except the `CrudRepository`. Which dependencies do you have? Do you have only the `spring-data-commons`? Or a *implementation* like JPA or Mongo...?

Comment: I'm using JPA. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Comment: I tried changing the GlobalPropertiesServiceImpl class as `@Component` and tried `@Qualifier` with `@Autowired` in the GlobalPropertiesLoader class, and still it fails.

Comment: @drunkenfist I think you need to show us the `BaseRepository`. Did you try it with the `CrudRepository`?

Comment: Yes, I did try with CrudRepository, but it didn't help. I have updated my question with the code for BaseRepository.

Comment: @drunkenfist Ok, I tried it with `jpa` and your `BaseRepository`. It works for me. :-/